# How to wait for a event to be processed in a protractor end to end test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have very simple *AngularJs 1.4.8* Front-End:

[image]

When the form is filled and the **OK** button is pressed the new person is added to the table.

The form is in the `addingPersonController` and the table is in the `allPersonsController`, both are childs under the `masterController`.

When a user is added(**OK** clicked) the following happens:

1. a `POST` request is sent to the server in order to add the new person.
2. a `personAddedEvent` is emitted with `$emit` from the `addingPersonController` to the `masterController`
3. the `masterController` broadcasts an `updatePersonsEvent` to the `allPersonsController`
4. the `allPersonsController` sends a GET request to the server in order to get all the persons and update the table.

**I have a protractor end to end test that exercises this case**, the problem is that I can not figure out how to wait for the whole process to finish before to check the assertions and the test always fails.

The UI works when tested manually and I have tried to wait in the protractor test with:

- `browser.wait(function(){}, timeout);`
- `browser.sleep(ms);`
- `.click().then();`

None of them worked.
**Is there a way to wait for such a process to complete before checking the assertions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got some similiar issues with my e2e tests too. There are couple of work-arounds can be added. Depend on situations , mostly due to some sort of non-response timeout (lost synchronization between protractor/selenium and browser). It is like a hang of the PC, cause by lack of resource (either `GPU/VRAM`, `RAM` or `CPU`). And this cause the built-in **"wait for angular works to be done"** of protractor lost its tracking. And run the spec before it should be ran.

Here is the list I will suggest you to try:

1. **use built-in wait for angular** Quick and solve the problem most of the time. But it will have nothing to deal with the lost synchronization between protractor/selenium and browser.

`browser.waitForAngular();`

2. **use [ExpectedConditions](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) with `browser.wait()`** This is always the best because it will sure work for all case. Even outside angular environment. Bad thing about this is... it is quite long to type

`browser.wait( ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement( $('#someId'), "Person's Name"), 10000);`

***EDIT:*** typos and make answer more understandable